# Nginx multiple websites behind different domain paths

Tags: nginx, node.js, jira, confluence

Is it possible to route different paths to separate websites?

I got the following scenario:
1 Home server with 1 IP e.g. 192.168.178.30

On this server are the following services installed:

```
- Jira - http://IP:8080/
- Confluence - http://IP:8090/
- Stash - http://IP:7990/
- Some Nodejs websites - http://IP:8000/ to http://IP:8005/
```

Now i want to hide the ports and just call the services by their names:

```
- http://192.168.178.30/Jira
- http://192.168.178.30/Confluence 
- http://192.168.178.30/Stash 
- http://192.168.178.30/Node1 or something
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it with nginx [proxy](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) module. Official docs have pretty detailed examples.

Comment: Is it called reverse proxy?

Comment: Oh ok you linked the page. Its hard to see the links. :) I will test my configuration with the documentation.